# Tapping on "Next" button on Soft Keypad takes focus on disabled field

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a screen which has 5 edittext field and the 3rd edit text field is disabled (`android:enabled="false",android:editable="false"`). When I tap on "Next" button of the Soft Keypad from 2nd Edit Text field, focus lands on the 3rd field (which is disabled) without a "Next" button in the Keypad to jump next fields.

I just wanted to check, if there is way we can make the Keypad skip the 3rd field and jump-to 4th field?

Thanks,
SKU

Comment: addidng android:focusable="false" under 3rd field did the trick